# Analyze a text file for certain attributes in Python 3.x

Tags: python, file, text

For an assignment in Python 3.x, I have to create a program that reads a text file and outputs the total number of characters, lines, vowels, capital letters, numeric digits, and words. The user has to provide the file and path of the text file. Asking for the file is easy:

```
file = input("Please provide the file path and file name. \nFor example C:\\Users\\YourName\\Documents\\books\\book.txt \n:")
f = open(file, 'r')
text = f.read()
```

I tried to use simple functions like:

```
numberOfCharacters = len(text)
```

...but reading farther into the assignment reveals that I have to use a `for` loop to analyze each character in the string, and then use a multi-way `if` statement to check whether it is a vowel, digit, etc.

I know I can count the number of line by counting the number of `\n`'s and I can use the `.split()` functions for wordsl but I am rather lost on how to get going.

I want to format the output like this, though I think I can figure this out after I get the program to work.

```
------------width=35---------|--width=8----
|number of characters        :       #####|
|number of lines             :       #####|
|number of vowels            :       #####|
|number of capital letters   :       #####|
|number of numeric digits    :       #####|
|number of words             :       #####|
```

Any help getting going and showing me what to do would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code to show for what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the NLTK toolkit (http://www.nltk.org/) to get the info you want.